# How to globally limit memory usage of git

Tags: git, memory, memory-usage

I have a Virtual Private Server where all my products' git repositories are. The problem is that while I fetch from it, the VPS dies out of memory. So I have to limit the memory usage. I know how to do that for each client's .git/config (pack.windowMemory, pack.packSizeLimit).

Is there a way to set the limit on the server and globally for all git repositories on the server?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by user by using the built in `limits.conf`. You could add all the Git users to an arbitrary group then limit the memory for that group.

But I'm not really condoning this, as if it needs memory - *it needs memory*. I would just imagine the Git process would terminate early as its out-of-memory - saving the VPS from crashing, but not really achieving anything.

### A way to do it ...

Eg. Your Git group is called gitgroup and you've got 3 existing users, bob, jane and tim

Create the group `gitgroup`

```
groupadd gitgroup
```

Then add the users to that group

```
usermod -a -G gitgroup bob
usermod -a -G gitgroup jane
usermod -a -G gitgroup tim
```

Now in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
#groupname  type  item  limit
@gitgroup   hard  rss   512000
```

This will limit that group (thus any user in it) to a hard memory limit of 512000KB. This may have other side effects too on other running processes owned by those users.

It may be more preferable just to add a memory limit to the particular users shell when they log in.

You could do this by add this to the user's respective `.bash_profile`

```
ulimit -v 512000
```

### The solution ...

You need more RAM. If you are trying to do something and run out of memory in the process - then either don't do what your doing, or add more memory. Clearly your hardware is insufficient for what your trying to do.

Comment: What appends if the limits.conf value is reached and the server process still need ram ? Does the request fails ?